# How to stop an (InputScope = Number) textbox from disappearing when it gains focus?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have searched for other answers, but none are clear enough.

I have a problem where whenever I click on a textbox that I set the InputScope to "number", the number pad comes up but the box I was typing in disappears..

Here is a screenshot and my code.
(I am also overriding the light/dark theme on windows phone to do it)

```
   <TextBox InputScope="Number" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    

   Margin="159,190,0,0" Name="aTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227"     

   TextChanged="aTextBox_TextChanged" Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="0" 

   Background="White" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that there is a different visual state for when the TextBox has input focus, which matches the phone theme you're trying to override. If you want to fight against the system theme, you'll need to retemplate the TextBox.

In Blend, in the *Objects and Timeline* window, right-click on the **TextBox** and select **Edit Template | Edit a Copy...**

In the dialog that appears, name your new style / template and where you want to create it in the XAML. Click **OK**.

You are now in template edit mode. (If you want to exit this mode, click the **Return scope** button at the top of the *Objects and Timeline* window)

[image]

Click on the **States** tab (or go to **Window | States** if not visible) and you can see all the different visual states for each mode of the TextBox (focused, unfocused, etc). As you click on each one, you'll see the TextBox in the designer change. Select each state and change the colors to what you want them to be.

Specifically, note how in the **Focused** state, the TextBox background becomes transparent by default. This is your issue. Change it to what you want it to be.

Finally, I want to recommend that you *don't* try to override the Light / Dark theme on Windows Phone, unless you are replacing it outright with your own branding / color scheme. It's a lot of work and it could annoy and confuse users who are used to seeing the theme they have chosen.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<TextBox Text="NumericTextBox">
<TextBox.InputScope>
    <InputScope>
        <InputScopeName  NameValue="Number" />
    </InputScope>
</TextBox.InputScope>
```