# Set Background color of ApplicationPage Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

My Windows phone application working fine with dark color scheme but When the device's theme is set to light my background become white due to that my buttons disappear. How can i set my app background to black even device theme is light???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
find LayoutRoot and set the Background to your choice of color.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the response at [How to stop an (InputScope = Number) textbox from disappearing when it gains focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031764/how-to-stop-an-inputscope-number-textbox-from-disappearing-when-it-gains-foc/15042452#15042452) for more information on templating controls to override the default system theme.

Also note that I recommend *not doing this* for the sake of forcing light or dark theme. Unless you've got your own custom branding / color scheme, this is a lot of work and could be annoying / confusing to the user.